# free command vs System Monitor in Linux Mint 17.2

Tags: linux, memory, ram

I do not understand difference in these 2 things:

1. When I use `free` command in shell and the output says that my used memory is 3,4GiB out of 3,7GiB.
2. When I open System Monitor program in left bottom Menu button and open tab Resources, section Memory and Swap History says that there is 1,4GiB memory used out of 3,7GiB.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? I more beleive the second program because now I have only mozilla and shell opened and this is the ouput.

Answer (score 2):

`free` output in *used* column includes buffers and caches. This is described in [`man free`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/free.1.html):

> **used**   Used memory (calculated as **total** - **free** - **buffers** - **cache**)

Subtract *buff/cache* from *used* and the value should match the one reported by System Monitor.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to fit. But does it really mean that my free RAM is 3,7GiB - _used column_ + _buffers/cache_ ?

Comment: Kernel caches reads to memory, which shows up in *caches* column. Since the data in read caches are usually on disk/available elsewhere, read caches can be dropped instantly if processes require more RAM.